# GCP n1-standard-1 pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

n1-standard-1 is 1vCPU and  3.75GB of ram.

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing) pricing per CPU and per GB of ram it should be:

```
0.031611 /vCPU hour - 0.031611 * 1 vCPU      * 24 hours * 30 days = 22.75
0.004237 /GB hour   - 0.004237 * 3.75 GB Ram * 24 hours * 30 days = 11.43
```

That's around 34 dollars.

But the GCP calculator and the monthly costs in the same documentation shows as 24$ per month. Is it due to sustained use discounts?

```
Machine type    Virtual CPUs    Memory  Price (USD)
n1-standard-1   1               3.75GB  $24.27
```

In the test environment I lost a lot of free credits than expected from GCP calculator. So I'm not sure which one to consider.

Comment: You need to show details. There are several reasons. Sustained use discounts. A compute engine VM has several charges beyond just the VM. Disks. snapshots, network egress, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result is correct, and the answer of the pricing calculator also!!

If fact, you forget a detail: [SUD. Sustained Use Discount](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts). As you can see, if you let a VM up full time, you can have up to 30% of discount with N1 VM (20% with N2).

$34 -30% is about $24. Everyone is correct!